# How can i make a table on a website using js by taking user inputs of number of rows and columns with custom inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

try to make it using vanila html css js/////tq

```
function getit(){
    let rows = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0].value
    let col = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].value
    let thead=document.querySelectorAll("input")[2].value
    let tablerow = "<td>"+thead+"</td>"
    let tablecol = "<tr> </tr>"

    // console.log(rows,col)
    // prevhtml=document.querySelectorAll("table")[0].innerHTML
    let prevrow="";
    
    for (let i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        prevrow=prevrow+tablerow  
    }
    console.log(prevrow)

    let prevcol="";
    for (let i = 0; i<col; i++) {
        prevcol=prevcol+"<tr>"+prevrow+"</tr>"
    }
    console.log(prevcol)

    document.querySelectorAll("table")[0].innerHTML=prevcol;  
}
```

Don't judge please...Learned js yesterday only
I have been working on this since yesterday ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `let tablecol = "<tr> </tr>"` you can use `tr = tbl.insertRow()` and nested loops:

```
tbl = document.querySelectorAll("table")[0]
for (let i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
    tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (let i = 0; i<col; i++) {
        const td = tr.insertCell();
    }
    tbl.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <div id="hello">
        <!-- your generated table code will be avaiable here -->
    </div>

    <script>

        // str is a variable that will be used for generating table contnet as string        
        let str="<table border='1'>";

        //to take input from user for number of rows requried by the user    
        let row=parseInt(prompt("Enter Number of rows you want to add in your table : "));

        //to take input from user for number of cols required by the user
        let cols=parseInt(prompt("Enter Number of cols you want to add in your table : "));

        //this loop will run for number of rows value entered by the user
        for(let i=1;i<=row;i++){
            str=str+"<tr>"

            //this loop will run for number of cols value entered by the user    
            for(let j=1;j<=cols;j++){

                //data variable is used here to take input from the user for every cell of the table
                let data=prompt("Enter data in row "+i+" and col "+j);
                str=str+"<td>"+data+"</td>";
            }
            str=str+"</tr>";
        }

        str=str+"</table>";

        //here we are takeing the div elemnt and putting table inside the div element with id hello
        document.getElementById('hello').innerHTML=str;
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).